# Cannot import a package installed with pip

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to add a package for my python(2.7.6) on linux ,
I used the command:

```
 pip install crc16
```

and It sends back :

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): crc16 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages
```

As should be.
 But when i try to run a python script it says

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mos.py", line 1, in <module>
    import crc16
ImportError: No module named crc16
```

My guess is that pip and the python aren't on the same version.

EDIT**
answer: i used `easy_install-2.7 crc16`
and then `python2.7 mos.py`

Comment: "crc16 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5" , you have the python3 version, it's strange if you use pip and not pip3, what 'which pip' returns ?

Comment: /usr/local/bin/pip @polku

Comment: please use `pip freeze` to see the installed package is coming in the list of installed packages in python

Comment: it returns crc16==0.1.1
@ChitrankDixit

Comment: okay you can try out using `which pip` and then `which python` on the terminal are these heading to the same path

Comment: python ->  /home/myname/bin/python

 which pip-> /usr/local/bin/pip @ChitrankDixit

Comment: Your python installation is in your home folder? That doesn't seem right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `pip` is catching the `3.5` version. You must specifically install `pip` for `2.7` version for your code to work. This is how it's done:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python2-pip
$ sudo pip2 install crc16
```

Comment: "E: Unable to locate package python2-pip" :/

Comment: Try, `sudo python get-pip.py` which specifically installs `pip` and `pip 2.7` followed by `sudo pip install crc 16`

Answer (score 4):

You could have done

```
python -m pip install <module>
```

Comment: /usr/bin/python: No module named pip
@Seekheart